# Individual DB start in SQL DB Stacking

Tags: sql-server, powershell-remoting

We have a scenario where multiple SQL DBs are installed under single SQL Instance (SQL DB Consolidation)

```
VM Name = MyHostQAS

SQL Instance Name = MyHostQAS\NISQLSERVER2

SQL DB1 = QWA

SQL DB2 = QWB
```

My Requirement is to write a PS script which remotely starts/stops Individual SQL DB (not the entire SQL Instance)

I tried with sqlcmd by first running it locally (in cmd) on the server where SQL Instance is installed

```
sqlcmd -S MyHostQAS\NISQLSERVER2 -Q "ALTER DATABASE QWA SET online;"
```

This works fine and QWA DB is started. Where as when we execute the following PS query we get errors

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username "admin" -Password "Admin123#" -ServerInstance "MyHostQAS\NISQLSERVER2" -Database "QWA" -Query "ALTER DATABASE QWA SET online;"
```

**Errors:**

> *Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'admin'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username "admin" -Password "Admin123#" -ServerIn ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
>   Invoke-Sqlcmd :  At line:1 char:1
>   + Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username "admin" -Password "Admin123#" -ServerIn ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand*

Can you please help in troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the database specified with the `-Database` argument is not online so the login fails. Specify a system database like `master` or `tempdb` for the argument:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance MyHostQAS\NISQLSERVER2" -Database "master" -Query "ALTER DATABASE QWA SET online;"
```

Not sure what is driving your requirement to toggle ONLINE/OFFLINE but you might consider turning on the database [`AUTO_CLOSE` option](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2160685/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-setting-the-auto-close-database-opt). That will free resources automatically when the database is not in use, but at the cost of startup overhead (not much different than setting the database ONLINE via script).

Comment: Thank you Dan, It worked when I changed -Database to "master". 


**Following Query worked :**

`Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance MyHostQAS\NISQLSERVER2" -Database "master" -Query "ALTER DATABASE QWA SET online;`